# How to get datetime differance in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am using laravel 4. But I am facing problem with finding the difference between two date: one coming from database table and another one is current datetime. From the date difference I am expecting 1 hour or 1 day. I've tried few solution but can't fix this yet. And also I don't know the better way to solve it. If you guys have any solution, please provide me an example. Please tell me if I need any library. Here is my code:

```
$lecture_id = Input::get('lecture_id');
        $delegate_id = Input::get('delegate_id');

        // $newDate = new Datetime();

        $lecture = Lecture::find($lecture_id);

        // $lec_date = Date::forge($lecture->start_time);
        // $lec_date = new Datetime($lecture->start_time);

        $lec_date = $lecture->start_time->diffForHumans(Carbon::now());


        if ( $lec_date > 1) {
            LectureDelegate::create(array(
                'lecture_id' => Input::get('lecture_id'),
                'delegate_id'=> Input::get('delegate_id')
            ));
            return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Your are successfully apply to the lecture');
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
 $lec_date = Carbon::createFromTimeStamp( strtotime( $lecture->start_time ) )->diffForHumans();
```

or possibly:

```
 $lec_date = $lecture->start_time->diffForHumans();
```

If you add this to your `Lecture.php` model:

```
public function getDates()
{
    return array('created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at', 'start_time');
}
```

From the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#date-mutators):

> By default, Eloquent will convert the created_at, updated_at, and
>   deleted_at columns to instances of Carbon...
>
> You may customize which fields are automatically mutated, and even
>   completely disable this mutation, by overriding the getDates method of
>   the model.

As for `diffForHumans` the [documentation](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#difference-for-humans) states:

> The lone argument for the function is the other Carbon instance
>   to diff against, and of course it defaults to now() if not specified.

---

**update**

If the timestamp from the database being passed to `diffForHumans` is in the future, Carbon automatically makes the return like:

When comparing a value in the future to default now:

- 1 hour from now
- 5 months from now

When comparing a value in the past to another value:

- 1 hour before
- 5 months before

Comment: Thank you for your time. Can you please tell me how I will get "before today" in Carbon.

Comment: @user3366155 did it work? If it did you can also accept the answer by clicking the check mark beside it. Goodluck :) **edit** will update my answer.